# How to avoid the white space which appears while switching between tabs in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working on a project based on Ionic. I have a page consisting of three tabs.
When I switch between the tabs there is a white blank screen appears for a short period of time, but it looks like the whole page is getting refreshed.What I want to achieve is that the tabs should remain as it is. It should not look like tab gets disappears and then appears.only the content should change.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-remove-the-empty-space-between-header-and-tabs-top/16066

Comment: @ MDaniyal: It seems like you didn't get my point. I get a whole white blank screen while switching between the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **show hide functionality.** in your design three tabs are there right. so in your application create one main div and in that div put your three tab and inside your controller **buy-default tab1 data show** on load **tab2 and tab3 div make hide**. and if you **click on tab2 then**  **hide data tab1 and tab3.** you do not change your whole page only data show hide. its faster and all header footer data as it is. and if you have any confusing then tell me.

Comment: I dont want to hide any tab. tab switching and content switching is working fine. but while switching it shows whole blank screen for short tie period